# Using strings with static variables?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem that involves 2 different scripts. What i am trying to achieve is to use Strings to access a static variable like the title suggest.

My First Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameInformation : MonoBehaviour 
{
    //Upgrades Info, 1 is bought while 0 is not bought
    public static int TipJar;
}
```

My Second Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Upgrades : MonoBehaviour 
{

public List<PlayerTank> playerList;
public class PlayerTank // Here is my class for PlayerTank
{ 

    public string Name;
    public string Value;

    // This is a constructor to make an instance of my class. 
    public PlayerTank (string NewName, int NewValue) 
    {
        Name = NewName;
        Value = NewValue;
    }
}

void Start() 
{

    playerList = new List<PlayerTank>();

    playerList.Add (new PlayerTank("TipJar", GameInformation.TipJar));

    //To loop all the list
    for(int i = 0; i < playerList.Count; i++)
    {
        int TempInt = i;

        playerList[i].NewValue += 1; //This line works but Gameinformation.TipJar will still contain the value 0, i want it to be 1.

    }
}

}
```

My goal is to update the value in `GameInformation.TipJar` but it keeps containing `0`.

I have tried to replace `playerList[i].NewValue += 1;` with `GameInformation.playerList[i].Name(which is TipJar) += 1`.

I  have been searching for some time now and I could not find a solution, any ideas?

Comment: This question is not very clear, what are you trying to achieve? Do you have an expected output?

Comment: Sorry, but what are you trying to achieve? Is very unclear

Comment: your GameInformation class has only defined a int var "TipJar"

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, my goal is just to make the value of GameInformation.TipJar to be 1 when inside the for loop();

Comment: This doesn't work because when you add GameInformation.TipJar to the player, the value is copied, not referenced in memory. So when you change player value, new value is changed, not the static field. If you want to be able to change GameInformation.TipJar through player class, take a look at object boxing/unboxing to pass the integer as reference instead as value.

Comment: @AleksandarToplek Thanks for the reply and suggestion,  but i am new to unity and can you please give me an example of how i should approach this issue with boxing/unboxing method?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this variable. What is the benefit of having an int being 1 when inside a loop? Why not just use a temporary variable that is set to one?

Comment: @xyLe_ I want to make the int 1 because this will indicate the tipjar item is bought and it is save using 'PlayerPrefs.SetInt("TipJar", GameInformation.TipJar)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sorry for the unclear question, my goal is just to make the value of GameInformation.TipJar to be 1 when inside the for loop();

Taking this comment from you, I assume that `GameInformation.TipJar` is meant to be global (meaning it should be 1 when in your loop, regardless of the content of `playerList`). I'll provide you 2 ways of solving your problem under this assumption:

**1. Use the static variable (the easy way)**

If that is correct, then just set the static like `GameInformation.TipJar = 1;` right before the loop starts and then set it `GameInformation.TipJar = 0;` right after the loop.

**2. Use reflection**

If you have a reference to your `GameInformation` object (say it is named `gio`), you can set its fields by the field name as a string with: `gio.GetType().GetField("TipJar").SetValue(gio, value)`. (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z33zd7h(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

If that doesn't answer your question, then I am sorry and I really don't get what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a typo?

Change

```
GameInformation.playerList[i].Name += 1; //This line will not work
```

to

```
playerList[i].Name += 1;
```

Also field `Name` is of type `String`, so i doubt that +1 makes sense here. I think you want something like

```
playerList[i].Name += (i + 1);
```